# Can spotlight locate/find files in a VM, specifically Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, ms-office, contacts, parallels-desktop

I run Windows 7 via Parallels 8 on my MBA running OS X10.8.4.

Is there a way to configure spotlight to locate/find contacts or emails in Outlook? Spotlight finds other VM created files such as Word, Excel or PPT, but doesn't register emails or contacts within Outlook.
Thoughts?

Thanks-

FH

Comment: I got it wrong :(

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely possible, but you will need to write your own Spotlight Metadata importer for Outlook database, because there is none.

Difficulty level: HARD

Here is documentation
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/MDImporters.html

Comment: Thank you. The process is beyond my scope, I'll just stick with searching via Outlook directly.